# Socket programing - constantly send and recive data (python)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm programing a very simple screen sharing program.
I have the code for sending and reciving the screen picture. I want the server to be able to recive data at any time, and I want the Client to send the data every 3 seconds. this is the code:

Server:

```
import socket
import zlib

def conv(code):
    with open('Image2.pgm', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(code)

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 100000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    str = zlib.decompress(data) 
    conv(str)
    print "All OK"
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import zlib

def PrtSc():
    ImageGrab.grab_to_file("Image.pgm")
    f = open("Image.pgm", "rb")
    Image = f.read()
    Image = zlib.compress(Image)
    return Image

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 100000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(PrtSc())
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Consider using https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: Did you have a question?